# Continuity of $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

If $u(x, y)$ and $v(x, y)$ are continuous (respectively differentiable) does it follow that $f(z) =u(x, y) + iv(x, y)$ is continuous (resp. differentiable)? If not, provide a counterexample.

This came up in a Complex Analysis book I've been reading, and it seems to me that the answer is obviously yes by Cauchy Riemann, but it is extremely unlike this text to make anything that straightforward, so I suspect I am missing something.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: $f$ is continuous. What do you mean by respectively differentiable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f$ is continuous, since

$$
\left|f(x, y)-f(x_0,y_0)\right|\leq
\left|f(x, y) - f(x_0, y)\right|+\left|f(x_0, y) - f(x_0, y_0)\right|=\\
\left|u(x) - u(x_0)\right|+\left|v(y)-v(y_0)\right|
$$

and since $\left|x\right|, \left|y\right| \leq\left|z\right|$, it follows easily from continuity of $u$, $v$.

$f$ is not necesserily complex differentiable, though. It is well known that $z\mapsto \bar{z}$ is not complex differentiable (it does not satisfy Cauchy-Riemann), but that's $f$ for $u(x) = x$, $v(y) = -y$.

Answer (score 0):

If u and v are continuous anywhere (that is, its values and the values of its limits are equal anywhere), so will do any possible linear combination of them... even if one of the coefficients is an imaginary number.

f will be continuous and differentiable (at least as many times as the lesser differentiable of the two functions u and v).